# Addin multiple sub-elements with same tag to en XML tree with Python/Elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am reading data from a  python dictionary and trying to add more book elements in the below tree. Below is just an examplke, i need to copy an element with it's child(s) but replace the content, in this case i need to copy the book element but replace title and author.

```
  <store>
    <bookstore>
        <book>
            <title lang="en">IT book</title>
            <author>Some IT Guy</author>
        </book>
    </bookstore>
  </store>
```

I use this code:

```
root = et.parse('Template.xml').getroot()
bookstore = root.find('bookstore')
book = root.find('bookstore').find('book')
```

Then i run the loop through a dictionary and trying to add new book elements under the bookstore:

```
for bk in bks:
    book.find('title').text = bk
    bookstore.append(book)
```

The result is that book elements are added to the bookstore, however they all contain title from the last iteration of the loop. I know i am doing something wrong here, but i can't understand what. I tried:

```
book[0].append(book) and book[-1].append(book)
```

But it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changing the same object.

You need to actual copy the object with copy.deepcopy

Example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import copy

root = et.parse('Template.xml').getroot()
bookstore = root.find('bookstore')
book = root.find('bookstore').find('book')

bks = ["book_title_1", "book_title_2", "book_title_3"]
for bk in bks:
   new_book = copy.deepcopy(book)
   new_book.find('title').text = bk
   bookstore.append(new_book)

print et.tostring(root)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Pavel. I have suspected that my way to copy the element was the root cause of issue! 
I tried your example and it worked right away!

Comment: I thought the tag being the same name was preventing from adding multiple tags with same name, but apparently, I was wrong. I'm amazed that this works. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing instead of `books.append(book)` you mean `bookstore.append(book)`.

Basically here you have a structure:

```
- store
  - bookstore
    - book
      - book infos
```

with `book = root.find('bookstore').find('book')` you are actually getting a reference to the (only) one you already have, and in the loop you keep updating its title and re-appending it to the store (so basically you are only overwriting the title). What you must do is to create every time a new [`Element`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) (or clone it as [Chertkov Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49261244/1029516) suggested, but you must remember to overwrite *all* the fields, or you may end up inheriting the wrong author) and append it to the bookstore:

```
for bk in bks:
    new_book = et.Element('book')

    # create and append title
    new_title = et.Element('title', attib={'lang':'eng'})
    new_title.text = bk
    new_book.append(new_title)

    # add also author and any other info
    # ...

    # append to the bookstore
    bookstore.append(new_book)

print et.tostring(root)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. From the behavior i was sure it behaves as you explained, but i did not know to overcome this issue.